# What is the difference between DESKTOP_SESSION, XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP, and XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP?

Tags: linux, desktop, environment-variables, gui, specifications

I want to detect which desktop manager I am running, and I found out that there are three environment variables, `DESKTOP_SESSION` , `XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP` , and `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` which could help me do so. But what exactly is the difference between these three variables? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

Old question, but still highly ranked on Google, so worth answering in 2021.

You want to use only the official `$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`. Be careful that it is a *colon-separated **list*** (like `$PATH`), so don't assume it only contains a single value (even if it does in most DEs). If you prefer to handle a single value, use `$XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP`.

Official standards:

- [XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#recognized-keys), defined in the [Desktop Entry Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html) since its [version 1.2](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#idm45632483466576)
- [XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/pam_systemd.html#desktop=), best described in [`systemd`'s PAM](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/pam_systemd.html)
- `DESKTOP_SESSION` is deprecated. Some DEs/WMs still set it for the sake of backward-compatibility, for new software it is not needed. It's 2021 after all.

For more details, including a bash function to parse and test a desktop environment, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/645761/4919

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the *official* reasons are for having many different variables, most likely different window & display managers all do their own particular configurations.

But all of them look the same, so using any one should work...

Here's what Mint's XFCE has:

```
$ echo $DESKTOP_SESSION 
xfce
$ echo $XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP 
xfce
$ echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP 
XFCE
```

and also

```
$ echo $SESSION
xfce
$ echo $MDMSESSION 
xfce
$ echo $GDMSESSION 
xfce
```

Or (from `env`):

```
XDG_MENU_PREFIX=xfce-
UPSTART_JOB=startxfce4
```

Your best bet (if you've got `wmctrl`) may be this combined with grep/cut:

```
$ wmctrl -m
Name: Xfwm4
Class: xfwm4
PID: 5449
Window manager's "showing the desktop" mode: N/A
```

You can also be using a different Window Manager and Display Manager, and some different distributions store data in different places, so *confusion reigns supreme*. See these very related Q's:

- [How to determine which window manager is running](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72549/how-to-determine-which-window-manager-is-running)
- [How can I find which desktop enviroment I am using? [duplicate of above]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125062/how-can-i-find-which-desktop-enviroment-i-am-using)
- [Is there a simple linux command that will tell me what my display manager is?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20370/is-there-a-simple-linux-command-that-will-tell-me-what-my-display-manager-is)
- [How to detect the desktop environment in a bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116539/how-to-detect-the-desktop-environment-in-a-bash-script)